# An association from the table X refers to an unmapped class: System.Guid

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this class:

```
public class AttachmentLocation
{
    #region properties

    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid LocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual long IndexInLocation { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region contained foreign objects

    public virtual Attachment Attachment { get; set; }

    #endregion


    #region Methods need to override for CompositeId

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as AttachmentLocation;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (UserId == t.UserId && LocationId == t.LocationId && Attachment.Id == t.Attachment.Id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (UserId + "|" + LocationId + "|" + Attachment.Id).GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

I have this Fluent Mapping:

```
public class AttachmentLocaionMap : ClassMap<AttachmentLocation>
{
    public AttachmentLocaionMap()
    {
        Table("Metadata_AttachmentLocation");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.UserId, "UserId")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Attachment.Id, "AttachmentId")
            .KeyReference(x => x.LocationId, "LocationId");
        Map(x => x.IndexInLocation).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LocationId).Not.Nullable();

        HasOne(x => x.Attachment);
    }
}
```

which I register:

```
SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m =>
{
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentLocaionMap>();           
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<FriendDetailsMap>();
}).BuildSessionFactory();
```

I get this runtime error:

> An association from the table Metadata_AttachmentLocation refers to an
>   unmapped class: System.Guid
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: NHibernate.MappingException: An association from
>   the table Metadata_AttachmentLocation refers to an unmapped class:
>   System.Guid
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 19:  Line 20:  Line 21:             SessionFactory =
>   Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m => Line 22:             {
>   Line 23:
>   m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf();
>
> Source File: C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Infrastructure\Dal\Adapters\NHibernateAdapter\NHibernateHelper.cs
>   Line: 21
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MappingException: An association from the table
>   Metadata_AttachmentLocation refers to an unmapped class: System.Guid] 
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:342
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompileForeignKeys(Table table,
>   ISet done) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:1169
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:1120
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:1249
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in
>   d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:227
>
> [FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration
>   was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons
>   collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> - Database was not configured through Database method. ]
>     FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in
>     d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:232
>     Ugi.Infrastructure.Dal.Adapters.NHibernateAdapter.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()
>     in C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>     2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Infrastructure\Dal\Adapters\NHibernateAdapter\NHibernateHelper.cs:21
>     Ugi.Infrastructure.Dal.Adapters.NHibernateAdapter.NHibernateHelper.GetSession()
>     in C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>     2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Infrastructure\Dal\Adapters\NHibernateAdapter\NHibernateHelper.cs:36
>     Ugi.Infrastructure.Dal.Adapters.NHibernateAdapter.NHibernateDal`1..ctor()
>     in C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>     2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Infrastructure\Dal\Adapters\NHibernateAdapter\NHibernateDal.cs:16
>     Ugi.Infrastructure.Dal.Adapters.NHibernateAdapter.NHibernateDalFactory.GetDal()
>     in C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>     2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Infrastructure\Dal\Adapters\NHibernateAdapter\NHibernateDalFactory.cs:17
>     Ugi.Server.Sources.Logic.SourcesService..ctor() in
>     C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>     2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Server\Sources\Logic\SourcesService.cs:36
>
>     BuildUp_Ugi.Server.Sources.Logic.SourcesService(IBuilderContext ) +153
>     Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>     context) in
>     c:\EntLib\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\DynamicMethod\DynamicMethodBuildPlan.cs:37
>     Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>     context) in
>     c:\EntLib\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:43
>     Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>     context) in
>     c:\EntLib\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\StrategyChain.cs:110
>     Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>     existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in
>     c:\EntLib\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs:512
>
> [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = "Ugi.Common.Model.Sources.ISourcesService", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   Ugi.Server.Sources.Logic.SourcesService(). Exception is:
>   FluentConfigurationException - An invalid or incomplete configuration
>   was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons
>   collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> - Database was not configured through Database method.

How can I fix that?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are wrong:

```
public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
public virtual Guid LocationId { get; set; }
```

And so are these:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.UserId, "UserId")
    .KeyReference(x => x.Attachment.Id, "AttachmentId")
    .KeyReference(x => x.LocationId, "LocationId");
```

You should have proper references:

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
```

And mapping:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.User, "UserId")
    .KeyReference(x => x.Attachment, "AttachmentId")
    .KeyReference(x => x.Location, "LocationId");
```

Comment: but I want to seperate between `simple properties` and `contained foreign objects`. Isn't that possible? These 3 primitive type compose compositeId. I don't want to reference all the 3 of them, only the PK of two of them and reference of the third. cann't I ?

Comment: @EladBenda that's not the correct way to map relationships. You can always access `Attachment.Id`, which will give you the Attachment's id without the need for loading it from the DB.

Comment: can you explain your last comment? How will Attachment.Id will be filled if the whole Attachment obj will not be filled from the DB?

Comment: @elad - sorry, i didn't even look at your mapping.  just saw the message about the Database method and went down a whole other path.  diego is right about this, but i don't think cleaning this up will fix your problem.  maybe i'm wrong about that, though.  he's talking about lazy loading.  referencing a mapped entity will load a dynamic proxy rather than the object itself.  the proxy will return the id without loading the entire object.  it's only if you access a property other than the id that nhibernate goes to the database to get the whole object.

Comment: @EladBenda, @Dave is essentially right. That's how proxies work in NH,  which enables the existence of the `Load` method, and one of the reasons why NH is more powerful than EF.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to map simple properties in a composite key (it's not a "standard way" of relating things with a ORM, but in some cases it could help you) you can map the key using KeyProperty instead of KeyReference in this way:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.UserId, "UserId")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.AttachmentId, "AttachmentId")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.LocationId, "LocationId");
```

Comment: This one seems to actually answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Attachmentmodel properly reference AttachmentLocation as well? If not, you might want to try References() instead of HasOne

Comment: How would it help? these two tables are  bidirectional one-to-one relation. However in my code I need a reference only from AttachmentLocation to Attachment, and no visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

my fluent configuration looks like this instead:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(configuration)
```

of what you have

```
Fluently.Configure(configuration)
```

i'm not sure what is supposed to be different with the overload for configure, but given the message about not using Database method, i'd imagine this would fix it for you.

Comment: tried and got this exceptions:Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.Database(System.Func<FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.IPersistenceConfigurer>)' has some invalid arguments    and Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' to 'System.Func<FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.IPersistenceConfigurer>'

Comment: i wonder if we're using different versions of fluent nhibernate.  i'm on 1.2.0.712.  i see Database() with overloads for Func<IPersistenceConfigurer> and IPersistenceConfigurer.  think should work with the latter of those.

Comment: actually, looking at it again, i think your configuration object and mine are different.  i am creating mine with:var configuration =
    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    .ConnectionString(connectionString)
    .DefaultSchema(defaultSchema)
    .FormatSql();  this leads to a type of FluentNhibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration (which has a base type of PersistenceConfiguration).  looks like yours is coming from NHibernate instead of fluent.  that must be there difference in using Configure with configuration vs Database().